# TypeError: takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, class

I am looking to brush up on my python so I am writing a small test class. I am making a boy class, and trying to create an instance of Boy called "shy boy" that will say what kind of boy he is (a shy boy) and "hello"

```
class Boy(object):

    def __init__(self, name, shoe):
        self.name = name 
        self.shoe = shoe 

    def speak(s):
        return s

    def shoeShize(shoe): 
        return "my shoe size is " + shoe

    def myName(name):
        return "hello i am a " + name
#class shyBoy(Boy)
shyBoy = Boy("shy boy", 9)
shyBoy.speak("hello")
print shyBoy.name("shy boy")
```

Right now I am getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boy.py", line 17, in <module>
    shyBoy.speak("hello")
TypeError: speak() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

➜  ~ python boy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boy.py", line 19, in <module>
    print shyBoy.name("shy boy")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Thanks!

Comment: `.name` is the name itself, `"shy boy"`. If you want to call the method it's `myName`, but you don't need to pass in the name *again*; that's the whole point of a class, that it can store that state alongside the behaviour. Read up on `self`, e.g. in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `self` arg in your function names:

```
class Boy(object):

    def __init__(self, name, shoe):
        self.name = name 
        self.shoe = shoe 

    def speak(self, s):
        return s

    def shoeShize(self, shoe): 
        return "my shoe size is " + shoe

    def myName(self, name):
        return "hello i am a " + name
```

If you don't specify `self`, Python will default to thinking whatever the first arg you've given it is `self`. Unless you decorate the method with `@staticmethod`, `self` will always be the default first argument, and it is implicitly passed in. Thus, in your method call, you are technically saying `boy_inst.method(self, myarg)`. So if the function is only expecting `self` and you also give it `name`, then it will say "You've given me too many arguments." That takes care of the Argument number errors

For the string error you are seeing

`boy.name` is a class variable, not a function. Thus, saying `boy.name('hi')` is not setting the class variable, it is attempting to call a class method called `name`:

```
 def name(self, arg):
     return arg
```

You set `name` on instantiation of the class

```
shyboy = Boy("name", 9)
```

That will set the instance variables. To change these, you either need a method defined such as

```
# In my Boy class
def change_name(self, newname):
    self.name = newname
```

Or you can create a new class

Answer (score 0):

Speak needs to be passed `self` as a parameter, since you plan to call it from an instance of the class.

For your second issue, your *function* is named `myName`, while the property of the class is named `name`. If you want to print the associated `name` provided at initialization, just use `print shyBoy.name`. If you want to try to use the `myName` function, use `print shyBoy.myName("shy boy")`. Note the lack of parens for `name`, since it is not a function and thus takes no arguments.

(However, I'm a little confused as to why are you trying to pass `name` as an argument to `myName` if you already have saved it in your `__init__`?)